# shortest path column access pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, shortest-path

I am new to pyspark and I am currently learning it. I have a sample data set on which i have used shortestPath method of pyspark. The output looks something like this.....

id | distance

```
id | distance
1    [1 -> 0]
3    [1 -> 2]
2    [1 -> 1]
4          []
5          []
0    [1 -> 1]
```

I want to make a dictionary where the key would be id and the value would be the distance so...

```
{1:0, 3:2, 2:1, 4:-1, 5:-1, 0:1}
```

but I don't how to access the distances column. -1 is for [].

Comment: can you try doing .toDF() on the final output ?

Comment: Just use `explode` on `distance` column. Thereafter, create a `struct` column using the values of `id` and the 2nd column of `distance` within a case statement

Answer (score 1):

First extract map values and lit(-1) where needed

```
df=df.withColumn('key',when(col('distance').isNotNull(),map_values(col('distance'))[0]).otherwise(lit(-1)))
```

#create dict

```
{row['id']:row['key'] for row in df.collect()}


{1: 0, 3: 2, 2: 1, 4: -1, 5: -1, 0: 1}
```